# Question about safe=True parameter for update operation of mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Im working a mongodb database using pymongo python module. I have a function in my code which when called updates the records in the collection as follows.

```
for record in coll.find(<some query here>):
   #Code here
   #...
   #...
   coll.update({ '_id' : record['_id'] },record)
```

Now, if i modify the code as follows :

```
for record in coll.find(<some query here>):
   try:
       #Code here
       #...
       #...
       coll.update({ '_id' : record['_id'] },record,safe=True)
   except:
        #Handle exception here
```

Does this mean an exception will be thrown when update fails or no exception will be thrown and update will just skip the record causing a problem ?

Please Help
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the replies.What i want to know is will safe=True , lead to an exception been thrown in case of a failed update, which i can handle in my except block ?

Answer (score 3):

`try` and `except` never cause an exception to be thrown. They simply handle thrown exceptions.

If `update` throws an exception on failure, the `except` will handle the exception, then the loop will continue (unless you use `raise` in the `except` clause).

If `update` doesn't throw an exception on failure, but instead returns `None` (or something like that), and you **want** it to throw an exception, you can use:

```
if coll.update(...) is None: # or whatever it returns on failure
    raise ValueError # or your custom Exception subclass
```

Note you should always specify which exception you want to catch, and only surround the lines of code where you want to catch it with `try`, so you don't hide other errors in your code:

```
for record in coll.find(<some query here>):
   #Code here
   #...
   #...
   try:
       coll.update({ '_id' : record['_id'] },record,safe=True)
   except SpecificException:
        #Handle exception here
   except OtherSpecificException:
        #Handle exception here
   else:
        #extra stuff to do if there was no exception
```

See the [`try` Statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), [Built-in Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html), and [Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: I think he was asking about the behaviour of `update` and not `try`.

Comment: Yeah, looks like maybe I misunderstood. I'll delete it if he indicates it's not what he was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Using `safe=True` will cause exceptions (of type `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure` or subclasses) to be thrown (see [the pymongo docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) for more information) if the database responds with an error. For example, here I cause a duplicate key violation on a unique index:

```
>>> db.bar.insert({'a': 1, 'b': 1})
ObjectId('4e4bc586c67f060b25000000')
>>> db.bar.ensure_index('a', unique=True)
u'a_1'
>>> db.bar.insert({'a': 2, 'b': 1}, safe=True)
ObjectId('4e4bc71fc67f060b25000003')
>>> db.bar.update({'a': 2}, {'a': 1}, safe=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 368, in update
    spec, document, safe, kwargs), safe)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 770, in _send_message
    return self.__check_response_to_last_error(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 718, in __check_response_to_last_error
    raise DuplicateKeyError(error["err"])
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index: test.bar.$a_1  dup key: { : 1 }
```

(Note that `DuplicateKeyError` is a subclass of `OperationFailure`, so `except OperationFailure: ...` would work as expected).

In addition to `update()`, `save()`, `insert()`, and `remove()` all accept the `safe` keyword argument. You can also set `safe` at the `Connection` level, so that you don't have to include it in each call that modifies the database.