# What is the return value for a successful MongoDB operation with mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to make a rule and/or regarding what does mongoengine return as success code for an operation. I might be wrong, but from what I've tested, there is sometimes a 1 returned for "Operation successfully performed", other times there is a 0. Is there any rule for this?

In the mongoengine documentation there isn't any mention regarding the return value of the DB operations.

I just want to build my application knowing for sure that if I run:

```
result = MyDocumentClass.objects(id=document_id).update_one(**update_dict)
```

or:

```
result = MyDocumentClass.objects(id=document_id).delete()
```

and the result=1 (or 0 whichever is the code for SUCCESS), that operation has definitely succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/d77b13efcb9f096bd20f9116cebedeae8d83749f/mongoengine/queryset/base.py), [`update()`](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/7b4d9140af99b35d8df06d964576ee1ddb9d8558/mongoengine/document.py#L376) returns the number of updated documents, [`delete()`](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/7b4d9140af99b35d8df06d964576ee1ddb9d8558/mongoengine/document.py#L396) doesn't return anything  (in other words, returns `None`).

Personally, I think the most reliable way to determine the success of operation is to see whether the command throws an exception or not. For example:

```
try:
    MyDocumentClass.objects(id=document_id).update_one(**update_dict)
    result = 1
except mongoengine.errors.OperationError:
    result = 0
    # process exception (log, for example)
```

Note: in order to make `MongoEngine` not to fail silently and throw exceptions, you need to enable `safe` mode by setting [`write_concern`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=write_concern#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update) argument, see also:

- [Question about safe=True parameter for update operation of mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092407/question-about-safe-true-parameter-for-update-operation-of-mongodb)

Comment: That's the problem, that from my experience, a failed update operation doesn't throw any exception, it just returns an int or nothing at all - like you said about delete.

Comment: @Clara yeah, I think setting [`write_concern`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=write_concern#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update) would help.

Comment: @Clara - define failed - an operation that it didn't update anything because the query part didn't match? Thats still a successful operation in terms that it worked.  If theres a server error then it will throw an exception.  However we should return what pymongo returns for delete so it would be worth opening a ticket on github to make that so!